# MagicalRecord and how to handle database change on application update?

Tags: ios, iphone, updatemodel, magicalrecord-2.2

I am using Magical Record in my app and it is working just fine. First version is already on app store. Now I have made some updates, database model has changed (some new entities + relationships), and i would like to update my app on app store.

But i fear these modifications will break my app, because model for database has changed. In app delegate i call;

```
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:[DataManager defaultStoreFileName]];
```

This line sets up the database, but I am not really sure how it does. Does it every time delete the previous database and sets up new with same path? If it does that my problem is solved, but it doesn't seem to work that way.

The other solution I am considering is to delete database if version of app has changed. And then call this line of code.

To make it clear how do i handle from database perspective app update?

Comment: You need to look at this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html